# Runtime error 13 in a for i loop, which used to work

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

**Background:**

I want to hide columns in a sheet based on whether there is an *x* in row 7. The x is not typed in but filled in via a formula.

I used the following code in another worksheet, were it works. The only thing I changed is the name of the sub, the worksheet and the row (7 instead of 5).

However whenever I try to manually run this sub from the vba editor as a test, it produces a runtime error 13 (mismatched type).

```
Sub hidCol2()

 Dim i As Long

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Zeitplan")
 ws.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

 For i = Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1

  If Cells(7, i) = "x" Then Cells(7, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

 Next i

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**My Question:**

Why does the above code produce a runtime error 13, what do I need to correct?

Comment: Try `If trim(str(Cells(7, i))) = "x" Then`  or `If Cells(7, i).Value = "x" Then`

Comment: You need to tell us which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Try `If Trim(Cells(7, i).Text) = "x" Then Cells(7, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True` changing to that line will surely work

Comment: You have not dimensioned `ws` and you are not qualifying what worksheet the cells and columns your for-loop is working on, but apart from that I don't see anything that should raise an error in your code (it runs fine for me in a workbook with a sheet named "Zeitplan"). The latter of the issues I mentioned *could* cause it though.

Comment: @Santosh your line worked, if you offer it as an answer I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Zeiram I'd check your formula that is filling in the 'x' then as it is leaving whitespace around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is :

Note it works without `Dim ws` but I think it's a good practice to dimension the variables before use.

If anyone can let me know why `Dim ws` here wasn't necessary that would clear some doubts in my head.

```
Sub hidCol2()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet                  'As Suggested by @eirikdaude but I don't know why it worked without it as well (Tested on a workbook with a single worksheet)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Zeitplan")
 ws.Activate
 ws.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

 For i = ws.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1

  If Trim(ws.Cells(7, i).Text) = "x" Then ws.Cells(7, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

 Next i

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If  you put `Option Explicit` at the top of (every) module, then you will need to have that `Dim` statement.  And it is highly recommended you put `Option Explicit`, always!

Comment: It wasn't necessary because he didn't have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Strictly speaking it is never necessary to dim the variables, if you don't, and leave option explicit off, the compiler will simply create the variables as it encounters them. If you want a more in-depth explanation about option explicit, and why leaving it out very easily can lead to headaches, it might make for a decent new question, although there are some fairly similar ones already: http://ow.ly/YtsjW

Comment: If you can expand on why the comparison fails because there are whitespaces around it, I'd find it interesting. I do find it a bit weird that the comparison fails just because of that.

Comment: @eirikdaude The comparison didn't failed it worked with or without that. The comparison earlier failed becasue there were trailing or leading white spaces along with character `x` hence trim removes and get's the text only from each cell in that range.

Comment: Then the comparison should return false, not return a runtime error.

Comment: @eirikdaude Because there must have been comparison with different data types I don't have his workbook otherwise this would have been clear